# Stopping Fritz from throwing away my position

Tags: fritz

I have Fritz 14 SE on Windows. If I set it to analyse a game or position, when I come back it has thrown away my game/position and is analysing some other position, which I think it has got from the internet. This does not happen if I disconnect my computer from the modem, but that is a nuisance. Does anyone know how to stop this?